# Regex readability suspicion numbers

Tags: regex

Could someone please tell me the numbers in this regex, the rest is clear to me only 0, 1, 2, and only to make sure the last block () * means more right?

```
^
(?<first>{{0})
\s*:\s*
(?<second>{{1})
(?<third>\s*>>\s*{{2})*
$
```

Comment: There are unmatched left-braces (`{`). Is this intentional, or an accident?

Comment: that was confusing me are they unmatched if so it would be a bit more clear for me ;)

Comment: @Mikatsu You should remove one of these opening brackets for every parameter.

Comment: was using just online Tools yet its build in some c# code, thanks this one braces for every Parameter was the failure
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}` are parameters, passed to the regex as a string.

Comment: oh ok and why it Looks like this {{0} 2 bracket open 1 Close?

Comment: Well, I guess this particular code is not working due to those brackets.